# How do I rewrite a URL that needs to capture both the REQUEST_URI and the HTTP_HOST?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite both the REQUEST_URI and the HTTP_HOST but I'm getting a redirection error when I implement this:

```
# Capture mysite.com/pages/123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/[0-9]+/?$
RewriteRule ^/pages/([0-9]+)/?$ /home/mysite/www/pages.php?id=$1
# Now capture the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+).mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) $1&subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like the following;

```
# This will map requests like 
# http://XXX.mysite.com/pages/123?somevar=someval&more=more2
# to /dir/pages.php?id=123&subdomain=XXX&somevar=someval&more=more2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+).mysite.com
RewriteRule ^/pages/([0-9]+)$ /dir/pages.php?id=$1&subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

The first RewriteCond on `%{REQUEST_URI}`  is probably unnecessary, because it contains the path component of the requested URI, which is already available in the RewriteRule Pattern match.